# Access Controll in Vaadin 14 without Spring

Tags: vaadin, cdi, shiro, jaas, vaadin-flow

Example:

```
Route - Accessable by (Roles)
LoginView - Any
UserView - User, Admin
AdminView - Admin
```

**What are the best practices to build access controll for such a scenario in Vaadin 14?** Preferably with either Annotations at the routes or a central location where access controll is configured.

All documentation seems to be targeted towards spring.
They mention vaadin-cdi should provide helpers, but it doesnt, thus I assume this is an artifact from Vaadin 8.

There are hints that JAAS or Shiro can be used, but there seems to be no examples or any documentation on how to include them.

Answer (score 2):

[Here is an article](https://medium.com/@erik.lumme/simple-access-control-in-vaadin-cbc1c5751ff5) I wrote on the subject. The complete code can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/eriklumme/tutorials/tree/master/simple-access-control-in-vaadin/simple-access-control-in-vaadin).

This doesn't use annotations, however, it just checks if the user is logged in for every view.

To use annotations, first create an annotation or use a suitable one. Then modify the ServiceInitListener so that it addition to checking if the user is authenticated, it also checks if it has the proper role(s).

You get the view that is being navigated to with `beforeEnterEvent.getNavigationTarget()`, there you can extract the annotations. How you store and retrieve the current user's roles depends on your setup.

The above approach is without using any framework for the security.

Comment: If the article goes down or the github repo disappears, this answer by itself is not very useful. SO 'requires' the important parts to be in the answer. Can you improve?

Comment: isnt it a security flaw that it uses the BeforeEnterEvent? At the point where this listener is triggered, the classes are already constructed, aren't they?
It would be nice, to be able to intercept before.

Comment: The bug https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/4595 was fixed some versions ago, but after the article was released.

It's not a security issue if you do the initialization on attach, but I will update the project to use a Vaadin version that contains the fix.